# elastic search with poco entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, elasticsearch

I have poco entities and each parent entity has its own child Foreign Key data like FK_Owner_User.

```
public class Listing
{
public int Id{ get; set; }
public int Status { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public virtual User FK_Owner_User{ get; set; }
}
```

**When I get parent class with dbcontext, I added it to elastic search index**

```
public ElasticClient ElasticClient
        {
            get
            {
                var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");

                var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                    node,
                    defaultIndex: "index_name"
                );

                var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
                return client;
            }
        }


DBContext dbContext = new DBContext();
            List<Listing> listings = dbContext.Listings.Where(l => l.Status == 1).Take(10).ToList();
            foreach (var listing in listings)
            {
                ElasticClient.Index(listing)
            }

var results = ElasticClient.Search<Listing>(body =>
      body.Query(query =>
       query.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(productListRequestModel.SearchKey))));
            return results.Documents.ToList();
```

but I see that foreign keys are null. My question is when I added poco entities to elastic client index, how can I populate foreign key data ?

Thanks in advance.

Unal

Comment: Two questions: Are you sure that your Listing objects come with its User instance from DB? What is the Func<> that you are using in the query?

Comment: octavioccl no I am not sure I am cheking right now. Second answer is I dont understand your question. Where am I using Func<> ? Thank you very much

Comment: This: productListRequestModel.SearchKey

Comment: @octavioccl  Listing objects come with its User instance from DB but when I index , It is getting null :/

Answer (score 0):

To find all documents of the same type you could do this:

```
  var listingResult2 = client.Search<Listing>(s => s.AllIndices());
```

The returned documents should come with their User.

If you want to filter the documents depending on the value of a property, for example,all `Listing` documents that have status as 1, you could do this:

```
 var listingResult = client.Search<Listing>(sd => sd.Query(q => q.Term(l => l.Status, "1")));
```

Comment: Hi @octavioccl, thanks but it is not working for me. Still User object in the listing is null.

Comment: rare, it works in my case, which version of elasticsearch are you using and also which version of NEST?